# WSO2 APP manager tomcat to read config file while start up

Tags: wso2

I have the web application deployed as a war in WSO2 app manager1.0.0.The web application has a config file which must be started while the server/tomcat server starts.Where can I have this located or any configurations need to be made so that the config file is read and prepared for the web application to run smooth.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to host back-end Web Apps on WSO2 App Manager itself. 
WSO2 App Manager is intended to be used for proxying.

Therefore you can place the web application on a different server. i.e Tomcat / WSO2 Application Server etc.